# Fixed Effects Quantile Regression (rqpd) with more than on type of fixed effects possible?

Tags: r, quantreg, quantile-regression

I try to estimate the effect of GDP (in cubic terms) on CO2 emissions. To estimatethe effect across the distribution of CO2 emissions I want to perform a quantile regression. To decrease omitted variable bias, I want to include country fixed effects as well as decade fixed effects. I use the rqpd package provided by Koenker and Bach, especially the Penalized Fixed Effects (PFE) method.

The data consist of 3247 observation. The code is as follows:

```
    library(rqpd)
    y = df3_avg_10$CO2
    x1 = df3_avg_10$GDP
    x2 = df3_avg_10$GDP2
    x3 = df3_avg_10$GDP3
    s = cbind(df3_avg_10$Country, df3_avg_10$Decade)

    Quantile_avg <- rqpd(y ~ x1+x2+x3 | s, data = df3_avg_10, panel(taus=c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9), tauw=rep(1/5, 5)), method = "pfe", na.omit)
```

This yields the error message: `` Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,  :   replacement has 6494 rows, data has 3247 ``

If I only include Country fixed effects, the code works. Therefore, my question: Is it possible to include more than one type of fixed effects in rqpd? Or is there any other option to estimate fixed effects in quantile regression?
I checked the 'lqmm' and 'quantreg' packages but couldn't find anything related. thank you very much in advance for any advice!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but your error suggests it is not. So including Decades as dummy variable and only having Country factor in 's' the fixed effect factor is the standard way to go.